# C# MenuStrip Panel visual anomalies

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem, menustrip

I'm coloring a menustrip to match my apps theme. However, every time I attempt it, I get this strange visual anomaly to the left of panel separators (the white rectangle) There is also some odd positioning of check-boxes also (possibly related?).

What is causing this, and how do I remove it?

Thank you

[image: Menu Strip Issue]

[image]

Example code:

```cs
private Color MainColor = Color.FromArgb(39, 40, 34);

public class MenuStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);

        if (e.Item.Selected)
        {
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(24, 25, 19);
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
        }
        else
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(MainColor))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Item.ForeColor = Color.White;
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSeparator(ToolStripSeparatorRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderSeparator(e);
    }

    public MenuStripRenderer() : base(new MenuStripColors()) { }
}

public class MenuStripColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripContentPanelGradientBegin
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripContentPanelGradientEnd
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }

    public override Color MenuBorder
    {
        get { return MainColor; }
    }
}

// In the forms Load()
this.menuStrip1.Renderer = new MenuStripRenderer();
this.menuStrip1.BackColor = MainColor;
this.menuStrip1.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to override the ImageMargin drawing, too:

```
protected override void OnRenderImageMargin(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e) {
  //base.OnRenderImageMargin(e);
  using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(MainColor)) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.AffectedBounds);
  }
}
```

I don't know what is causing your check mark issue since I can't duplicate that issue on my machine.  I'm guessing maybe that's a graphic DPI setting in your windows.

Comment: You were right regarding the white rectangle! Thanks so much. I'll play with my DPI settings and see what happens. I'm running on a 4k monitor, so I have scaling at like 225% or something